# What does "1;" mean in Perl?

Tags: perl, perl-module

I have come across a few Perl modules that for example look similar to the following code:

```
package MyPackage;

use strict;
use warnings;
use constant PERL510  => ( $] >= 5.0100 );

require Exporter;

our @ISA = qw(Exporter);  
our @EXPORT = qw( );

{  #What is the significance of this curly brace?

    my $somevar;

    sub Somesub {
      #Some code here 
    }
}

1;
```

What is the significance of `1;` and of the curly braces that enclose the `$somevar` and the Sub?

Comment: Also, [Why do you have to put a 1 at the end of a perl5 module?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3606528/why-do-you-have-to-put-a-1-at-the-end-of-a-perl-5-module) and [Cool return values](http://returnvalues.useperl.at/values.html).

Comment: I'm disappointed that tchrist didn't submit an answer for this.

Comment: Technically, this is two questions in one. I normally try to nip these in the bud and edit one question out before answers come in, but it's too late now.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

`1` at the end of a module means that the module returns `true` to `use/require` statements. It can be used to tell if module initialization is successful. Otherwise, `use/require` will fail.

`$somevar` is a variable which is accessable only inside the block. It is used to simulate "static" variables. Starting from Perl 5.10 you can use keyword [`state`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/state.html) keyword to have the same results:

```
## Starting from Perl 5.10 you can specify "static" variables directly.
sub Somesub {
    state $somevar;
}
```

Comment: Upvote because this answer is both concise and correct and actually answers all of the parent's questions.

Answer (score 11):

When you load a module "Foo" with `use Foo` or `require()`, perl executes the `Foo.pm` file like an ordinary script. It expects it to return a true value if the module was loaded correctly. The `1;` does that. It could be `2;` or `"hey there";` just as well.

The block around the declaration of `$somevar` and the function `Somesub` limits the scope of the variable. That way, it is only accessible from `Somesub` and doesn't get cleared on each invocation of `Somesub` (which would be the case if it was declared inside the function body). This idiom has been superseded in recent versions of perl (5.10 and up) which have the [state](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/state.html) keyword.

Answer (score 9):

Perl modules must return something that evaluates to true. If they don't, Perl reports an error.

```
C:\temp>cat MyTest.pm
package MyTest;
use strict;
sub test { print "test\n"; }
#1;  # commented out to show error

C:\temp>perl -e "use MyTest"
MyTest.pm did not return a true value at -e line 1.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at -e line 1.

C:\temp>
```

Although it's customary to use "1;", anything that evaluates to true will work.

```
C:\temp>cat MyTest.pm
package MyTest;
use strict;
sub test { print "test\n"; }
"false";

C:\temp>perl -e "use MyTest"

C:\temp>  (no error here)
```

For [obvious reasons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrases_from_The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy#The_number_42) another popular return value is **42**.

There's a list of cool return values maintained at http://returnvalues.useperl.at/values.html.

Answer (score 8):

Modules have to return a true value. `1` is a true value.

Answer (score 4):

The curly braces limit the scope of the local variable $somevar:

{
  my $somevar;
...
} # $somevar's scope ends here

Answer (score 4):

From the documentation for [require](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/require.html):

> The file must return true as the last
>   statement to indicate successful
>   execution of any initialization code,
>   so it's customary to end such a file
>   with 1;  unless you're sure it'll
>   return true otherwise. But it's better
>   just to put the 1; , in case you add
>   more statements.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about Perl, but usually you create a scope using curly braces. Probably $somevar shoudln't be available globally?