# Why do you have to put a 1; at the end of a Perl 5 module?

Tags: perl, module

Why do all Perl 5 modules have to end with `1;`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does 1; mean in Perl?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1940182/what-does-1-mean-in-perl)

Answer (score 25):

> A Perl module must end with a true value or else it is considered not to
>    have loaded.  By convention this value is usually 1 though it can be
>    any true value.  A module can end with false to indicate failure but
>    this is rarely used and it would instead die() (exit with an error).

source: [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_module)

Comment: i've seen `'false';` used before as a true value... :)

Comment: Dominus once [quipped](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.perl.misc/msg/a95715144dccec82?hl=en), “I have very rarely used … [`'Cogito ergo sum';`](http://perl.plover.com/qotw/misc/r006/TestExpand.pm) which as everyone knows is self-evidently true in all possible universes.  This ensures maximum portability.”

Comment: This doesn't answer the question: _why_ must a module end with a true value?

Answer (score 7):

That's because `use Module LIST;` is equivalent to `BEGIN { require Module; Module->import( LIST ); }` (see [perldoc -f use](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/use.html))

Particularly, `require Module;` can be implemented with the following bit of code (from [perldoc -f require](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/require.html)):

```
sub require {
  my ($filename) = @_;
  if (exists $INC{$filename}) {
    return 1 if $INC{$filename};
    die "Compilation failed in require";
  }
  my ($realfilename,$result);
  ITER: {
    foreach $prefix (@INC) {
      $realfilename = "$prefix/$filename";
      if (-f $realfilename) {
        $INC{$filename} = $realfilename;
        $result = do $realfilename; ## HERE
        last ITER;
      }
    }
    die "Can't find $filename in \@INC";
  }
  if ($@) {
    $INC{$filename} = undef;
    die $@;
  } elsif (!$result) { ## AND HERE
    delete $INC{$filename};
    die "$filename did not return true value";
  } else {
    return $result;
  }
}
```

See that `do $realfilename`? Look at [perldoc -f do](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/do.html), and you'll see that it's the equivalent, pretty much, of `eval system("cat $realfilename")`, which basically means slurp the file in, and eval it.

Looking at [perldoc -f eval](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval.html) yields: "In both forms, the value returned is the **value of the last expression evaluated inside the mini-program**". That is, the last statement in the file.

It's worth to mention that if the last "statement" is a subroutine declaration, that does not constitute a true value:

```
$ perl -le'$r = eval "sub a {1}"; print $r ? "true" : "false"'
false
```

Whereas a `1;` after it does:

```
$ perl -le'$r = eval "sub a {1} 1"; print $r ? "true" : "false"'
true
```

Looking again at the `sub require` above, and with the knowledge of what `require` and `do` does, the `$result` that the `do $realfilename` returns is indeed the last statement `eval`ed from the file, which is indeed the last statement in the file.

If such last statement isn't a true value, the `## AND HERE` `elsif()` I highlighted would be called, and the `require` would die as the module does not return a true value.
The `use Module` would also die, as it's doing a `require` behind the scenes.

Long story short, it doesn't matter what you end the file with, as long as it's a value that is understood as being `true` by perl. Samples on the wild (CPAN) include `1;`, although some these days rather end their files in `1` (no missing semicolon), and others just weirdly use stuff like `'0 but true';` or `'supercalifragilisticexpiralidous';`, all of which are parsed as "truish" values by Perl.