# Why does this Perl code use a 1; statement?

Tags: perl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do you have to put a 1; at the end of a Perl 5 module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3606528/why-do-you-have-to-put-a-1-at-the-end-of-a-perl-5-module)

From this page [**Perl::Critic::Policy::Subroutines::RequireFinalReturn**](http://perlcritic.com/pod/Perl/Critic/Policy/Subroutines/RequireFinalReturn.html), this is a code sample

```
package Password;
# every time the user guesses the password wrong, its value
# is rotated by one character
my $password;
sub set_password {
    $password = shift;
}
sub check_password {
    my $guess = shift;
    if ($guess eq $password) {
        unlock_secrets();
    } else {
        $password = (substr $password, 1).(substr $password, 0, 1);
    }
}
1;
```

- Why is a `1;` used at the end? What does that statement signify to the compiler?

I tried code [with](http://www.ideone.com/PrAEy) and [without](http://www.ideone.com/0vW7Y) it. Result looks the same.

Comment: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3606528/why-do-you-have-to-put-a-1-at-the-end-of-a-perl-5-module/3606543#3606543

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's because a Perl module has to return "true" in order for it to work as a module. If a module doesn't return true, it's assumed that its initialization failed and it's equivalent to calling `die`. It's not required if the code isn't used as a module, though, so unless you try using the code example as a module as well, you won't see the difference.

`1;` is just probably one of the most concise ways of returning true.

If you take a look at [this site](http://returnvalues.useperl.at/values.html), you'll see that people are being pretty creative with their return values.

Comment: okay, thats basically anything except `0`, `'0'`, `undef`, `''`, `()`, `('')`.

Comment: @Lazer : Even `'false'` is true.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a quote from [perldoc -f require](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/require.html):

> The file must return true as the last
>   statement to indicate successful
>   execution of any initialization code,
>   so it's customary to end such a file
>   with 1; unless you're sure it'll
>   return true otherwise. But it's better
>   just to put the 1; , in case you add
>   more statements.

If I delete the `1;` from your module, then try to [use](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/use.html) it in another script, I get a compile error:

```
Password.pm did not return a true value
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted
```