# What happens if you don't put 1; at the end of a package?

Tags: perl

What happens if you don't put `1;` at the end of a package? For example, if I remove the `1;` from the following script, the code still runs:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

package Foo;
print "Begin and Block Demo\n";

BEGIN { 
    print "This is BEGIN Block\n" 
}

END { 
    print "This is END Block\n" 
}

1;
```

Is the `1;` mandatory for package creation? I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3606528/why-do-you-have-to-put-a-1-at-the-end-of-a-perl-5-module), but it doesn't explain what happens if the `1;` is omitted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a little tricky.  It is simply required, if the package will be loaded by `use` or `require`.

From [require](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/require.html)

> The file must return true as the last statement to indicate successful execution of any initialization code, so it's customary to end such a file with `1;` unless you're sure it'll return true otherwise. But it's better just to put the `1;`, in case you add more statements.

The [use](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/use.html) comes down to `require`, so whenever you `use` a module the last statement that returns must return true, otherwise the compilation fails. A simple way to ensure this is to put `1;` at the end. If you never `use` (or `require`) that package *then* you don't have to have the `1` (true) in it.

The code in a file brought into the program via `use` actually runs and it must end up returning true, as required by `require`. If the file is read in in another way then there is no notion of 'return'.

If it is run as an executable then again there is no requirement on true return, since `require` isn't involved. However, we generally write packages in order to `use` them, not to run them as programs. So practically speaking there should *always* be a `1;` at the end.

The [perlmod](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html) would also be required reading.

---

Here is a simple example.  This

File **Mod.pm**

```
package Mod;

# print "hello\n";    # works with this line uncommented
```

File **script.pl**

```
use Mod;
```

when run by `perl script.pl` prints

```
Mod.pm did not return a true value at main.pl line 1.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at main.pl line 1.
```

When a package is `use`d it *must* return a true value.  If the last return is from a statement which happens to return true, like the commented out `print`, then all is well again.

But we can run `perl Mod.pm` regardless of what it returns.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot  Thank you, you are right, it must be that.  I've adjusted the answer. It wasn't clear enough to me that `package Name;` is designed to be run.  And I've seen shebang line at all kinds of places.

Comment: I don't think it's designed to be run, the OP is just new and doesn't know how modules work yet.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Right,  that seems clear (now). I didn't get it fully right away.

Answer (score 3):

When you `use` a `.pm` file, the file must return a true value (such as `1`) to indicate success, or else the `use` statement will fail and compilation will be aborted.

But packages, as such, don't have to end with a true value; it's just that usually each package goes in its own `.pm` file, and the file needs the `1` in order to be `use`-able. In your example, where the package is put directly inside an executable script, no `1` is needed.

Comment: We don't actually see the code that is using the package. It looks like a script because of the shebang but there is nothing under the package. If the op only does perl or perl -w to the shown code it's not even a real module. It's just code in a different package than main.

Comment: @simbabque: It doesn't just "look like a script"; rather, the OP explicitly described it as one, and said that he ran it. I don't know why you expect there to be any other code using the package; the OP's experiment makes perfect sense as-is.

Comment: It does, but I read the second part of your answer as when you are putting the package not in its own file but in the same as the script that's using it. Then you don't need `use` but you could still `import` if you wanted and there was no need for the true statement. Everything you say is correct, but that case is missing.

Comment: @simbabque: I'm sorry, I don't understand your last comment. What case is missing?

Comment: I think I just started from a different angle. Just re-read your answer again. It's fine like it is. I must not have been fully awake. Sorry :-)

Comment: @simbabque: No worries. :-)